# Complex Number Division definition?

Tags: quaternions

$\frac{(a,b)}{(c,d)} = \left ( \frac{ac + bd}{c^2 + d^2}, \frac{bc - ad}{c^2 + d^2} \right )$ if $(c,d) \ne (0,0)$

I'm dealing with quaternions in my book..complex numbers.
how do I derive..or proof (a,b)/(c,d)

Comment: Your question appears to be about complex numbers.  Why do you mention quaternions (which are completely different)?

Comment: quaternions can be viewed as a generalization of the complex numbers;

Comment: except that quaternions do not satisfy commutativity, so $\frac{x}{y}$ it is ambiguous whether you mean $\frac{1}{y}\cdot x$ or if you mean $x\cdot \frac{1}{y}$.  Those could possibly be different things.  For now, it is implied that you are working with complex numbers, not quaternions, since you have it written as a fraction.  Although you might be studying quaternions later on, you are not right this second and so mentioning them is only going to confuse people.

Comment: @user3513743 quaternions are an extension used to deal with an undefined operation. That is not an issue here.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck I understand saying that about the complex numbers, but which undefined operation do the quaternions resolve?

Comment: @MattSamuel it is a series of statements that are very difficult for me to recall. The answer is somewhere in the comments here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1832047/are-there-important-situations-where-we-study-false-statements-as-if-they-were-t

Answer (score 2):

$(a,b)/(c,d)$ is defined as $(a,b)$ times the inverse of $(c,d)$.

Let the inverse be $(p,q)$. Then you need
$$(c,d)(p,q)=1$$
$$(cp-dq,cq+dp)=(1,0)$$

First if $d=0$, then $c\ne 0$ and $p=1/c$, $q=0$.

Otherwise,
$$p=-\frac{cq}{d}$$
$$c\left(-\frac{cq}{d}\right)-dq=1$$
$$-\frac{c^2+d^2}{d}q=1$$
$$q=-\frac{d}{c^2+d^2}$$
$$p=\frac{c}{c^2+d^2}$$

It turns out the above expression also hold for the first case of $d=0$, as a special case.

Hence
$$\frac{(a,b)}{(c,d)}=(a,b)\left(\frac{c}{c^2+d^2},-\frac{d}{c^2+d^2}\right)$$
$$=\left(\frac{ac+bd}{c^2+d^2},\frac{bc-ad}{c^2+d^2}\right)$$